# Class Cast Exception from MapFragment to Fragment in android google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, classcastexception, android-maps-v2, mapfragment

Alright, here I am trying to make this app consisting of a navigation drawer and a map fragment.
My aim is to click on an item in nav drawer and it takes you to specified coordinates on the map.
But I'm encountering this Class Cast exception when I'm trying to access a method of my map fragment onClick of a nav drawer item.

Here's my map fragment...

```
  interface receiveData{

public void navigateToNewLocation(double lat, double lon);}
public class MAPFragment extends Fragment implements receiveData {

public  String IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID = "iconResourceID";
public  String ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
public  String GEO = "39.933333,32.866667";

public void setParameters(double lat, double lon){
    navigateToNewLocation(lat, lon);
}
// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;
  ImageView ivIcon;
  TextView tvItemName;
  MapView mapView;


  String[] coords = GEO.split(",");
  Double c1 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[0]));
  Double c2 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[1]));

  public MAPFragment() {

  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container,
                    false);
        Log.e("coords[0]",coords[0]);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
  }


 /**
   * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
   * */
  public void initilizeMap() {
      if (googleMap==null){
        googleMap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Log.e("In MAPFragment","Before coords!=null");


        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(c1,c2)));


          LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
          String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
          Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

          if(location!=null){
              onLocationChanged(location);
          }

          googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

              @Override
              public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
              }
          });

        //checking
        if(googleMap==null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      initilizeMap();
  }

  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // Getting latitude of the current location
      double latitude = location.getLatitude();

      // Getting longitude of the current location
      double longitude = location.getLongitude();

      // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
      LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

      // Showing the current location in Google Map
      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

      // Zoom in the Google Map
      googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

}

  @Override
  public void onDestroyView()
  {
      super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
      }

  public void navigateToNewLocation(double lat, double lon){

      Log.e("INSIDE navigateToNewLoc","next is cam pos");
        // On clicking a user       
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(lat,lon)).zoom(12).build();
         Log.e("INSIDE navigateToNewLoc","next is animateCam");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

  }
}
```

Here's my method which is used to configure the item in navigation drawer in MAinActivity

```
public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment = new MAPFragment();


Log.e("In main activity","Lets see what happens");



String[] coords = dataList.get(possition).getGeo().split(",");
Double c1 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[0]));
Double c2 = new Double(Double.valueOf(coords[1]));



    fragment.setArguments(args);



    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment existingFragment = frgManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);


    if(existingFragment !=null){

        ((receiveData)existingFragment).navigateToNewLocation(c1,c2);
    }
    else
     frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}
```

Here's My Log Cat

```
  09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): Process: com.findmeWithdrawer, PID: 31030
  09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030): java.lang.ClassCastException:         com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to com.findmeWithdrawer.receiveData
  09-10 03:00:00.784: E/AndroidRuntime(31030):  at       com.findmeWithdrawer.MainActivity.SelectItem(MainActivity.java:205)
```

Comment: where is your mainactivity

Comment: I have provided you with a method of the MainActivity from where the problem arises...I think that shud be enuff

Comment: It can be singled out that the problem exists in this line

((receiveData)existingFragment).navigateToNewLocation(c1,c2);

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a Fragment to an interface. That's impossible.

You want to cast it to your `MAPFragment` class which implemented that interface:

```
((MAPFragment)existingFragment).navigateToNewLocation(c1,c2);
```

That's because class `MAPFragment` implements `receiveData` interface, which contains your required `navigateToNewLocation` method.

Answer (score 0):

> You are casting a Fragment to an interface. That's impossible.
>   This is not true, you can cast classes to interfaces. Its ok.

Take a look at **package name**
**com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment**
Original google map fragment can not be casted to your interface. This is problem.